# How to convert hex values to floating point number in python

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, hex

I have hex value `4396 eccd`. If I convert it to floating point number using some [online calculator](https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/), I get value as `301.85` which is correct.

But when I convert it using python, I get some different value:

```
>>> float.fromhex('0x4396eccd')
1133964493.0
```

can anyone please help me on why its showing wrong value in python. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For understanding what `fromhex()` do, you can refer this : https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/fromhex.html

Instead of using `fromhex()` for hex string to float number, you should better use `struct` module.

In python 2.x

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('!f', '41973333'.decode('hex'))[0]
18.899999618530273
```

In python 3.x use:

`bytes.fromhex('41973333')` instead of `'41973333'.decode('hex')`

So it will be as follows:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('!f', bytes.fromhex('41973333'))[0]
18.899999618530273
```

Comment: Your solution gives me this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: Sorry my bad. Check it again.

Comment: For me it is working. Did it worked for you? If it worked then please do mark it as solved and if not then please let me know.

Comment: Thanks can you have a look at this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60770615/how-to-merge-two-hex-values-to-make-it-one-python

Comment: I have answered that in a comment. @SAndrew

Comment: Did that solved your problem? That you just deleted that question? @SAndrew

Comment: @AbhaySalvi But why does float.fromhex give the wrong value though?